# Creating PDF file from remote URL with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm struggling with this problem for quite a while and wanted to ask for help.
I'm trying to generate a PDF file from a `remote URL` in `PHP`. 
for example from `mysite.com?id=12` so when I click on this link the `browser's pdf viewer` opens with the contents of this URL `including all styles` etc.
I've tried it with `jsPDF` javascript library but it seems that it can't be used for remote URLs. I also found tons of libraries which all need API keys ( registration, subscription, payment ....).
I don't want to ask for code samples but just for instructions on which library is able to do that and the workflow.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might find mPDF useful. https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.

There is good documentation https://mpdf.github.io/ and even some examples in another GitHub repository https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples.

You can use html and css to generate a nice looking PDF.